# Ranking bond lengths of dienes

Tags: organic-chemistry

[image: Diene Structure]

For the bond lengths (ranking  them longest to shortest) I think that it would be A>C>B

My thought is that bond-B is a double bond (so the shortest), bond-A is the longest because it is only connected to one double bond when C is connected to two double bonds.

Does that logic work out for these problem types?

Comment: This is a bit tricky. B and C are very similar...

Comment: I'd say that $C$ is not really a single bond; it has a significant $\pi$ component to it. So yes, it is $A>C>B$

Comment: looking at this as 1, 4-dimethyl butadiene then I agree with your reasoning; A is longest (single bond) , B shortest and C slightly shorter than A but much longer than B as it has slight double bond character due to delocalisation of the butadiene.

Comment: Your answer is correct, but that's not the exact train of thought I would go along. "Connected to $n$ double bonds" doesn't make much sense unless you relate it to either hybridisation or bond order (via resonance forms).